# Types of Anomaly

Tags: mysql

The practice exam that I have been given does not come with solutions, and I'm not sure if my answer to these questions are correct.

> If a MYSQL is running at the read-committed isolation level, the auto commit mode is turned off, 
>   and the server allows multiple connections at the same time. The time window is indicated on the 
>   left side
>
> 1)
>   In this circumstance, is there any anomaly happening in T1 or T2 if there is, what would be the 
>   anomaly type?
>
> ```
> Time Frame    Transaction 1   Transaction 2
> 1             Read(X);        Read(Z);
> 2             X = X + 1 ;     Read(Y);
> 3             Update(X);      Y=Y-Z;
> 4             Commit;         Update(Y)
> 5                             Read(X)
> ```

My answer to question one was there was no anomaly as the transactions didn't effect the values that the other one was using.

> 2)
>   Will there be an anomaly in any of the following transactions? If there will be, what is the 
>   anomaly type?
>
> ```
> Time Frame    Transaction 1   Transaction 2
> 1             Read(X);    
> 2             Read(Y);        Read(X);
> 3             Insert_Into(X); Read(Y);
> 4             Commit;         Y = T + Y;
> 5                             Read(X);
> 6                             Update(Y);
> 7                             Commit;
> ```

My answer to question two was that it was Phantom Read, as it's occuring at the read-committed isolation level this is possible, and `Transaction 1` alters `X` while it is being read by `Transaction 2`.

Comment: Does `Read(X)` mean to read _row_ X?  If so, then what does `Insert_into(X)` mean?  If it means read _some_ row from the table `X`, then it is imprecise.  Do the reads have `FOR UPDATE` on them?  Sloppy test.